# Is Inverse Variance Weighting biased if my samples come from correlated data?

Tags: autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, weighted-mean

I have a brief question about whether or not inverse-variance weighting is a biased or unbiased estimator when the samples themselves are means of correlated data themselves. To elaborate on this, let's say I have 10 "measurements" which have a mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma^2_i$ each. The sample values are independent to one another but their mean and variance come from correlated samples themselves. Where $\mu_i$ is the mean of subsamples of a given measurement, $i$, and $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of those subsamples for a given measurement $i$ (this variance includes the statistical autocorrelation between the subsamples which emerge from markov-chain monte carlo).

I compute the total mean and total variance by using the weights as, $w_i = \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$, and taking the weighted mean $\mu_{ave}$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{10} w_i \mu_i$ / $\sum_{i=1} w_i$ and the variance as $\sigma^2_{ave}$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{10} w_i^2 \sigma^2_i$ / $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} w^2_i \right)^2$ The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) does mention that the individual measurements have to independent of each other but also unbias which I'm pretty sure values are. However, I'm not 100% sure about the variance as the wiki does state " if the measurements are performed under identical scenarios" and because my subsamples are correlated I'd assume this would invalidate this weighted-average.

I'm not 100% sure about this statement so I was wondering if someone else with more experience might be able to clarify some points for me! Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I cannot understand the apparently self-contradictory statement, "The sample values are independent to one another but their mean and variance come from correlated samples themselves."  Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: ah yes, that would be confusing! So, I'm doing this in the context of markov chain monte carlo. So, I have W walkers/chains of N samples each (so I have a total of W*N samples). The Walkers (that create the chains of N samples each) are independent of each other. The $\mu_i$ and $\sigma^2_i$ from above come from taking each value of W and calculating the mean/variance on all the N samples which result in W measurement (10 in the case above). Does that make it clearer?

Comment: So the $\mu_i$ and $\sigma^2_i$ values are independent of each other $but$ these values themselves are calculated via N samples themselves (from a given chain). This results in the $\sigma^2_i$ values being correlated due to them being drawn from a Markov chain so they're not i.i.d themselves but are still independent from each other). This is my main question, does the fact that the $\sigma^2_i$ values have autocorrelation within themselves (but are independent from one another) affected the inverse-variance weighted average. Does this autocorrelation introduce a bias to the estimator?